# Looking for multiple usernames in a Cisco device

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regular expression to search through a Cisco Router Configuration file for the use of multiple usernames.

Example:  Pass

username account1 privilege 0 password [stop here and proceed to next line]

Example: Fail

username account1 privilege 0 password [stop here and proceed to next line]
username [stop here]

I have come up with the following: 
username account1 privilege 0 password .*\n(.*\n)*.*username

but seem to have run into a Catastrophic Backtracking issue.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: Are `username`, `account`, `privilege 0` and `password` literal values, or will they need to match a specific regex pattern? When you come upon a line with `username...username`, do you want to parse the second `username` as though it had been written on its own line?

Comment: Username is a literal value
account is a variable value
the rest are literal values

Comment: This does not cause catastrophic backtracking. Please have a look at [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA8cA7/1)

Comment: that is what I thought but had other users tell me they had issues.

Comment: is there a way to streamline the code

Comment: Are you trying to determine when a single line contains more than a single `username` entry?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect that a line contains

```
username account1 privilege 0 password
```

but then does not contain an additional `username` on the same line, you can use a negative look-ahead:

```
/username account1 privilege 0 password(?!.*?username)/g
```

You can see that in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/cA8cA7/2). It simply finds the text that you want, then checks that text that you *don't* want (in this case, another `username`) will not occur later on the same line.